# Undefined variable getQuestion Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Message: Undefined variable: getQuestion

I am creating a multiple choice quiz using codeigniter. I am trying to pass getQuestion from the model to the view but i receive an undefined variable error. The view should display the question

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to get it to work, There are 7 Questions and because they display randomly, the question sometimes repeats. How can I fix this in the model?

Also so after the 7 questions, the quiz ends.

Model:

```
class Quiz extends CI_Model
{
    private $questionArray = array();
    private $answerArray = array();
    private $incorrectArray = array();
    private $incorrectArray1 = array();
    private $incorrectArray2 = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function startQuiz()
    {
    $this->db->select('*');
        $qres = $this->db->get('questions');
        $ares = $this->db->get('answer');

        foreach ($qres->result() as $row ) {
            $this->questionArray[] = $row->question;
        }


        foreach ($ares->result() as $row) {
            $this->answerArray[] = $row->c_answer;
        }

        foreach ($ares->result() as $row) {
            $this->incorrectArray[] = $row->i_answer;

        }

            foreach ($ares->result() as $row) {
            $this->incorrectArray1[] = $row->i_answer1;

        }
            foreach ($ares->result() as $row) {
            $this->incorrectArray2[] = $row->i_answer2;

        }

            //Retrieve question in random order
            $max = count($this->questionArray);
            $questionPos = rand(0, $max - 1);

            //retrieve question
            $getQuestion = $this->questionArray[$questionPos];
            //retrieve correct answer
            $getAnswer = $this->answerArray[$questionPos];
            //retrieve incorrect answers
            $getIncorrect = $this->incorrectArray[$questionPos];
            $getIncorrect1 = $this->incorrectArray1[$questionPos];
            $getIncorrect2 = $this->incorrectArray2[$questionPos];


            //retrieve wrong answer corresponding to the Question
            $wrong = $questionPos;
            while ($wrong != $questionPos) {
                $wrong = rand(0,$max-1);
            }
            $wronganswer = $this->incorrectArray[$wrong];
            $wronganswer1 = $this->incorrectArray1[$wrong];
            $wronganswer2 = $this->incorrectArray2[$wrong];

            //Random position of answers
            $choice = rand(0,1);
            if ($choice == 0) {
            $answer1 = $getAnswer;
            $answer2 = $wronganswer;
            $answer3 = $wronganswer1;
            $answer4 = $wronganswer2;

            }
           else 
             {
            $answer1 = $wronganswer;
            $answer2 = $getAnswer;
            $answer3 = $wronganswer1;
            $answer4 = $wronganswer2;

             }
        return array('id' => $questionPos,'getQuestion' =>      $getQuestion,'answer1' => $answer1,'answer2' => $answer2,'answer3' => $answer3, 'answer4' => $answer4);





    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 class Question extends CI_Controller
 {
     function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('quiz');
     }

     function start()
     { 
         $option = $this->input->get('name', false);
         $questionid = $this->input->get('id', false);

         if ($option === false) {
             $start = $this->quiz->startQuiz();
             $this->load->view('quiz_view', $start);
         } else {
             $this->load->view('quiz_view', array('name'=>$option));
         }
     }
 }
```

View:

```
   <h5><?php echo $getQuestion ?></h5>
```

Comment: That variable is only defined in your `startQuiz()` function, how about you do `startQuiz()['getQuestion']` to access it?

Comment: in the controller? It makes no difference.

Comment: Where did the error occur? Model or View or Controller?

Comment: Please paste the information of `var_dump($start)`  in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

In your code the getQuestion is not present when $option = false.

```
if ($option == false) {
     $start = $this->quiz->startQuiz();
         $this->load->view('quiz_view', $start);
 } else {
         $this->load->view('quiz_view', array('name'=>$option,'getQuestion'=>''));
 }
```

Comment: This should be your answer. Check this.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

Change:

```
     if ($option === false) {
         $start = $this->quiz->startQuiz();
         $this->load->view('quiz_view', $start);
     }
```

To:

```
     if ($option === false) {
         $data['start'] = $this->quiz->startQuiz();
         $this->load->view('quiz_view', $data);
     }
```

And on your view page print `print_r($start);`.